# How to change window time in stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a stream that makes aggregation by time using windowing for 5 minutes.

Could I change this parameter dynamically from 5 to 4 minutes using program сode?

Not creating the same stream.

I need to make selection from stream depends condition, if count of data more 1000 then wait4 minutes, if less then wait 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is currently possible in ksqlDB.  It sounds like what you need is a kind of session window, where the session window is closed based on something other than time, e.g. based on some count.

While this is not possible with ksqlDB's higher level abstract, it is possible with Kafka Streams.  You may want to take a look at that.